# Mysql group by same value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id   |   cat_id  |  value1  |  value2  |  value3
------------------------------------------------
1    |   cat1    |     a    |     b    |    c
2    |   cat1    |     b    |     e    |    h
3    |   cat2    |     n    |     r    |    c
4    |   cat2    |     h    |     d    |    m
5    |   cat2    |     k    |     d    |    a
6    |   cat3    |     g    |     d    |    m
```

I'd like to write a Mysql query that returns something like this:

```
cat1 => 
     [1] =>
         1,
         a,
         b,
         c,
     [2] =>
         2,
         b,
         e,
         h,

cat2 => 
     [1] =>
         3,
         n,
         r,
         c,
     [2] =>
         4,
         h,
         d,
         m,
     [3] =>
         5,
         k,
         d,
         a,

cat3 => 
     [1] =>
         6,
         g,
         d,
         m,
```

Is it possible?

Comment: what format do you want? As you written one line per `cat_id` all the values concatenated?

Comment: Try first on your own. Fetch the result loop through it and generate the desired array.

Comment: I think it's not possible

Comment: What kind of thing are values 1,2, and 3. Could there ever be a value4 or 5?

Comment: @aldrin27 you're joking, right?

Comment: To add to what @b0s3 said: Once you have tried, come back and show us the code you tried with and we can help from there

Comment: If you could write the `output` that you expect in a `tabular format` then it would be easy to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Maybe* you wanted something like

```
$result = 
    array (
      'cat1' => array (
       array ( 1,'a','b','c' ),
       array ( 2,'b','e','h' )
      ),
       'cat2' => array ( 
       array( 3,'n','r','c' ),
       array( 4,'h','d','m' ),
       array( 5,'k','d','a' )
      ),
       'cat3' => array (
       array( 6,'g','d','m' )
      )
    );
```

as a php array?

In that case you could collect the values with something like

```
$q=mysqli_query('SELECT cat_id,id,value1,value2,value3 FROM tbl
                 ORDER BY catid,id');
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_row($q)) $result[array_shift($r)][]=$r;
```

In the while loop the first column (`catid`) will be taken off the results array (using `array_shift($r)`) and be used as the key for a subarray to collect further values into. The `[]` after `$result[array_shift($r)]` will start this (new) sub-array and push the vector `$r` with the remaining columns `id,value1,value2,value3` into it.

Comment: Exactly! It works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the dollowing query:

```
mysql> SELECT id, cat_id, value1, value2, value3
FROM mytable GROUP BY id ORDER BY cat_id ASC
```